# How to show gimp image preview icon on osx

Tags: macos, gimp

How can I make OSX Finder or Desktop show a preview of the image instead of the gimp icon?

This happens automatically for jpg and bmp files etc.

Comment: Which image do you mean?

Comment: For example the image preview icon on the desktop shows the gimp icon. Also in Finder in Icon view also shows the gimp icon. Most other apps shows an an image preview, bmp, jpg, pdf etc.

Comment: Which image shows a GIMP icon - do you mean PPM images? GIF images? TIFF images?

Comment: it's the default gimp format which is xcf - all the standard formats like tiff, giff, png, bmp already shows a preview icon.

Comment: I think it's related to the *Quicklook* feature, maybe. See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/688